# Bootstrap 0 margins

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded all of the bootstrap files and there's no margin at all with anything (jumbotron, paragraph text, etc). On the example website, the text aligns horizontally with the beginning of the navbar text.

I tried adding .body{ margin: 10px;} to the css file, but that's useless because it's overridden everywhere, and I don't know if that's the best course of action. I did some research and I can't find anyone with similar problems.

Here's what I'm dealing with (Chrome 13in MacBook Air):

[[image: Current[1]]

Here's what i'm striving for: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/

Update: Console is blank and it looks like a left and right margin is never applied.

[image]

Comment: Checked your console for errors?

Comment: Nothing from the console!

Comment: Right-click and inspect elements, see if a margin setting has been overruled, or simply never applied.

Comment: Check your network tab as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have a wrapping `.container` element.

```
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: or a `container-fluid` for a full width site. also don't nest Bootstrap containers.

Comment: That takes care of the horizontal alignment! Is there a class I can add to take care of the vertical alignment? The jumbotron is still touching the navbar?

Comment: @SethKillian add a `margin-top` to your jumbotron?

Comment: In the getbootstrap.com example they have `padding-top: 70px;`  on `body`.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the Bootstrap css by referencing your own css file and marking the styling as "important" as below.

```
body {margin-top: 10px !important;}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: While true the OPs concern seemed to be that expected Bootstrap's CSS WASN'T being applied; not that it was applying something he wanted to override.  Also `!important` should almost never be an answer.